# Twitter Kit not Showing Videos in TimeLine

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, twitter-fabric

I seted a UITableViewController as TWTRTimeLineController and it shows tweets and everything but it doesn't recognizes videos. Thats really weird it shows them as only pictures. The code is very simple i don't know if Im forgetting anything.

```
import UIKit
import TwitterKit

class TimeLineController: TWTRTimelineViewController {

    var navController: personalNavController!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let client = TWTRAPIClient()

        self.dataSource = TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource(searchQuery: "#CamNowAppBeta", APIClient: client)
        self.showTweetActions = true 


    }

    func tweetView(tweetView: TWTRTweetView, didTapVideoWithURL videoURL: NSURL){
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

TWTRTweetViewDelegate method didTapVideoWithURL must be removed